# Letting forms interact with javascript in an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a web page to tell me if it's time for coffee based on an if/else statement. There are two variables which are based on user input: cupsDrank & lastCup. This interacts with an if/else statement making sure the time is before 14:00 and after 06:00.

Problem is, cupsDrank & lastCup don't seem to work out.

This is what I came up with in html:

```
<div>
    <form id="coffeeForm1">
        How many cups of coffee have you had today?<input name="cupsDrank" type="number">
    </form>
    <form id="coffeeForm2">
        How many hours ago was your last cup?<input name="lastCup" type="number">
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="coffeeTime()">Check</button>
    <p id="coffee"></p>
</div>
```

I've put the script source in the footer

```
<footer>
    <script src="myScript1.js"></script>
</footer>
```

And this is my what myScript1.js says:

```
let d = new Date();
let dhour = d.getHours();

    function coffeeTime() {

        let coffee;
        let cupsDrank;
        let lastCup;

        cupsDrank = document.getElementById("coffeeForm1").value;

        lastCup = document.getElementById("coffeeForm2").value;

            if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank == 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
                coffee = "It is time for coffee, but this is your last cup today.";
            } else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank < 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
                coffee = "It is time for coffee, rejoice!";
            } else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
                coffee = "You've had your coffee fill for today.";
            }  else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup < 2) {
                coffee = "You've had your coffee fill for today. Didn't you just drink a cup?";
            }   else if (lastCup < 2) {
                coffee = "Slow down cowboy. Didn't you just drink a cup?";
            }   else if (dhour < 6) {
                coffee = "You need sleep, not coffee.";
            }   else if (dhour > 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup < 2) {
                coffee = "It's past your coffee tax, you've already had your fill AND you've just had a cup. What's wrong with you?";
            }   else if (dhour > 14) {
                coffee = "It's past your coffee tax, no more for today!";
            }   else {
                coffee = "Does it really matter?"
            }
        document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = coffee;
    }
```

I think the problem is either in the way I'm trying to get the input out of the form, or in the lines which say

```
cupsDrank = document.getElementById("coffeeForm1").value;
lastCup = document.getElementById("coffeeForm2").value;
```

console.log(cupsDrank); outputs 
VM16739:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: cupsDrank is not defined
    at :1:13

console.log(lastCup); outputs
VM17097:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: lastCup is not defined
    at :1:13

Right now, when I press the button, it always outputs "It's past your coffee tax, no more for today!" regardless of form input. The time in the Netherlands is >14 so the else/if statement which should output that does work correctly.

I hope someone sees what's wrong, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are getting this error as the id is associated with the form and not the input. So assign id to input and try getting value from it like

```
<div>
    <form id="coffeeForm1">
        How many cups of coffee have you had today?<input id="i1" name="cupsDrank" type="number">
    </form>
    <form id="coffeeForm2">
        How many hours ago was your last cup?<input id="i2" name="lastCup" type="number">
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="coffeeTime()">Check</button>
    <p id="coffee"></p>
</div>

<footer>
    <script src="myScript1.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Javascript

```
let coffee;
let cupsDrank;
let lastCup;

cupsDrank = document.getElementById("i1").value;

lastCup = document.getElementById("i2").value;
if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank == 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
            coffee = "It is time for coffee, but this is your last cup today.";
        } else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank < 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
            coffee = "It is time for coffee, rejoice!";
        } else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup >= 2) {
            coffee = "You've had your coffee fill for today.";
        }  else if (dhour >= 6 && dhour <= 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup < 2) {
            coffee = "You've had your coffee fill for today. Didn't you just drink a cup?";
        }   else if (lastCup < 2) {
            coffee = "Slow down cowboy. Didn't you just drink a cup?";
        }   else if (dhour < 6) {
            coffee = "You need sleep, not coffee.";
        }   else if (dhour > 14 && cupsDrank > 3 && lastCup < 2) {
            coffee = "It's past your coffee tax, you've already had your fill AND you've just had a cup. What's wrong with you?";
        }   else if (dhour > 14) {
            coffee = "It's past your coffee tax, no more for today!";
        }   else {
            coffee = "Does it really matter?"
        }
    document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = coffee;
}
```